# Pass LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS to Poetry when adding packages

Tags: python, pyodbc

**Edit:** My workaround ended up being to add the `whl` file that was built outside Poetry to the repository, and adding the pyodbc as a file to Poetry.

---

I am trying to install pyodbc on my M1 Mac for a project, within the scope of Poetry.

Installing "outside" of Poetry is no problem, following the instructions on the [pyodbc wiki page.](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install)

However, when using `poetry add pyodbc` in a new project, I get an error stating that the `sql.h` file was not found.

I have a feeling that the fixes given in the pyodbc instruction page aren't available from within the Poetry environment somehow.
Any tips on how I can install this package within the Poetry environment? Is there a way to point Poetry towards the additional LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS?

[image]

Comment: This is almost never a "solution" so much as an easy way to get burned, but you can often do `export CONFIG_SITE=/path/to/some/file` and add environment assignments in `/path/to/some/file`.  There are a surprisingly large number of packages that invoke an auto-tool generated configure script that will honor CONFIG_SITE, and usually this causes more problems than it solves.  But in this case it might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Poetry *does* pass on `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`. I just received the same error and can confirm that the following worked on an M1 Mac:

```
brew install unixodbc
export LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/lib
export CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include
poetry add pyodbc
```

Using Poetry version 1.1.13 and Python 3.9.10

(Note: You can also use `poetry shell` to activate the virtualenv and run `pip install pyodbc` inside (after setting LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS). The built package should now be cached so you can add it with `poetry add` afterwards. Not an ideal solution though, since it will break on updates).

Update: There is an open pull request at https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/pull/870 that adds automatic detection of the paths using `odbc_config --cflags --libs`, feel free to upvote it.

Comment: I suppose the "real" question here is how to also make it friendly for colleagues installing this poetry environment without too much hassle - and for this I think keeping the `. whl`-file in the repository and adding the file instead of `poetry add pyodbc` is a more robust solution. But thanks for this additional insight!

Comment: I see, yeah, that's a valid workaround! Btw. I updated my answer to include a link to an open pull request which should simplify the installation. Hopefully there will also be prebuilt wheels available at some point.